# C++ argument list for alias template is missing

Tags: c++, templates

I use the “alias template” in my “ListNode.h”,there is the code:

> Note: IDE I use is visual studio 2019

```
//ListNode.h
#ifndef DSACPP_LIST_LISTNODE_H_
#define DSACPP_LIST_LISTNODE_H_

typedef int Rank;

template<class T>
class ListNode
{
private:
    T data_;
    ListNodePosi pred_; ListNodePosi succ_;

public:
    ListNode() {}; 
    ListNode(T e, ListNodePosi pred = NULL, ListNodePosi succ = NULL)
        : data_{ e }, pred_{ p }, succ_{ succ } {}


    ListNodePosi insertAspred(T const& e); 
};

// alias template
template<typename T>
using  ListNodePosi = ListNode<T>*;

template<class T>
ListNodePosi ListNode<T>::insertAspred(T const& e) 
/*
-⭐ there will be a error: argument list for alias template "ListNodePosi" is missing
*/
{
    ...
}

#endif
```

I don't konw how to resolve this error. So I'm here to ask for your help. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like a class template (in a non-deduced, C++17, context), you need to explicitly provide a template argument list when using an alias template.

```
ListNodePosi<single-type-template-argument> ...;
```

Your program contains several other errors, though:

- In the declaration and definition of the `ListNode` class template, the *name* `ListNodePosi` is not yet known, but is used,
- The `ListNode` ctor (the overload with arguments) refers to `p` when initializing `pred_` in its member initializer list: this should refer `pred`.
- prefer using `nullptr` over `NULL` (you actually need to include some `<c...>` header to have access to `NULL`, whereas the `nullptr` pointer literal comes natively as a keyword).

You can fix the first bullet above by starting with a forward declaration to `ListNode`, followed by the declaration of the alias template `ListNodePosi` (as it does not need `ListNode` to be complete), finally followed by the definition of `ListNode` which makes use of the alias template.

E.g.:

```
template <typename T> class ListNode;
template <typename T> using ListNodePosi = ListNode<T> *;

template <class T> class ListNode {
private:
  T data_;
  ListNodePosi<T> pred_;
  ListNodePosi<T> succ_;

public:
  ListNode(){};
  ListNode(T e, ListNodePosi<T> pred = nullptr, ListNodePosi<T> succ = nullptr)
      : data_{e}, pred_{pred}, succ_{succ} {}

  ListNodePosi<T> insertAspred(T const &e);
};

template <typename T> ListNodePosi<T> ListNode<T>::insertAspred(T const &e) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I got it. I learned a lot from your answer, and thank you again. 